# Не работает OnCollision2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать метод отнимания здоровья при столкновении с враждебным объектом. Использую теги Player и Enemy. Игрок и Враг соответственно.
Но при столкновении ничего не происходит. Но забавно, если я вставлю в Collision2D Игрока свойство:     Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel); то оно сработает. 
И вопрос какого чёрта?

Код Player:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int lives;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 3.0F;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 15.0F;

    new private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        lives = 5;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) Run();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) Jump();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Vector3 direction = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0F;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

     private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Damage();
        }

    }

    private void Damage()
    {
        lives-= 1;
    }
}
```

Код Enemy:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 3f;

    private float direction = -1f;

    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(speed * direction, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(direction, 1, 1);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
            direction *= -1f;
    }

}
```

Comment: collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" вот эта проверка конечно же срабатывает?

Comment: Да, а к чему вопрос?

Comment: я просто уточнил, в вопросе вы это не написали

Comment: А проводились ли тесты, что `if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")` выполняется?

Comment: Нет. А как это проверяется?

Comment: Ну хотя бы Debug.Log("!") внутри if'а сделайте. Вы никак не проверяли, но почему-то уверены, что if проходит. Наверняка проблема в том, что на одном из объектов тэг не стоит.

Comment: Я поставил Debug.Log(), но он ничего не выводит. В Play коллайдеры сталкиваются и ничего более

Comment: Господа я нашёл ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю так. Пропиши lives -= 1 в самом OnCollision в if.
Или сделай из private void Damage() в public или если не сработает делай то что я сказал первым способом.